# Jetty to support TLS 1.2 requests from SoapUI

Tags: java, jetty, soapui, embedded-jetty, tls1.2

I am struggling to build an embedded Jetty server which will accept TLSv1.2 requests.

This is the Java code:

```
private void launchHttpsListener() {

Server server = new Server(new InetSocketAddress(m_sAddress, m_nPort));

SslContextFactory sslContextFactory = new SslContextFactory();
sslContextFactory.setKeyStorePath("./keystore.jks");
sslContextFactory.setKeyStorePassword("Aa123456");
sslContextFactory.setKeyManagerPassword("Aa123456");
//sslContextFactory.setProtocol("TLSv1.2");
//sslContextFactory.setIncludeProtocols("TLSv1.2");

// Setup HTTP Configuration
HttpConfiguration httpConf = new HttpConfiguration();
httpConf.setSecurePort(m_nPort);
httpConf.setSecureScheme("https");
httpConf.addCustomizer(new SecureRequestCustomizer());

ContextHandler contextHandler = new ContextHandler();
contextHandler.setContextPath("/Service");
contextHandler.setHandler(new JettyServiceHandler());

ContextHandlerCollection contextHandlers = new ContextHandlerCollection();
contextHandlers.setHandlers(new Handler[] { contextHandler });

ServerConnector serverConnector = new ServerConnector(server,
    new SslConnectionFactory(sslContextFactory,"http/1.1"),
    new HttpConnectionFactory(httpConf));

serverConnector.setPort(m_nPort);

server.setConnectors(new Connector[]  { serverConnector });
server.setHandler(contextHandlers);

try {
    server.start();
    
    Log4jWrapper.writeLog(LogLevelEnum.INFO, "[-----------------] <JettyServiceListener> launchHttpsListener",
            "HTTPS Listener on " + m_sAddress + ":" + m_nPort);
    
    server.join();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {

    Log4jWrapper.writeLog(LogLevelEnum.ERROR, "[-----------------] <JettyServiceListener> launchHttpsListener",
            e.getMessage());
} catch (Exception e) {

    Log4jWrapper.writeLog(LogLevelEnum.ERROR, "[-----------------] <JettyServiceListener> launchHttpsListener",
            e.getMessage());
}
```

}

m_nPort = 9520

And this is the handler:

```
public class JettyServiceHandler extends AbstractHandler {

    @Override
    public void handle(String target, Request baseRequest, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws IOException, ServletException {

        Log4jWrapper.writeLog(LogLevelEnum.DEBUG, "[-----------------] <JettyServiceHandler> handle", "Received a notification...");
        
        String requestStr = convertStreamToString(baseRequest.getReader());

        Log4jWrapper.writeLog(LogLevelEnum.DEBUG, "[-----------------] <JettyServiceHandler> handle", "requestStr = " + requestStr);

               
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=utf-8");
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        baseRequest.setHandled(true);
        response.getWriter().println("1.2.1");
       
    }
    
    static String convertStreamToString(BufferedReader bufferedReader) {
        Stream<String> lines = bufferedReader.lines();
        return lines.collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
    }
}
```

From SoapUI I am sending a very simple request to some https address 135.136.137.138:9520

Currently I get the following error:

> ERROR:javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert:
> handshake_failure

The handler of course is not reached.

The keystore is self signed.

I have added the following to SoapUI-5.3.0.vmoptions:

```
-Dsoapui.https.protocols=TLSv1.2
```

Where do I go wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Found the missing link...

I added the following:

```
    sslContextFactory.setExcludeCipherSuites("SSL_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA",
                "SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA", 
                "SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA",
                "SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5",
                "SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA",
                "SSL_DHE_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA",
               "SSL_DHE_DSS_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA");
```

and the exception disappeared!

Comment: Note: that's list of exclusions has nothing to do with the TLS support level.  In fact, your `*_RSA_*_SHA` matching ciphers are actually unsupported by modern browsers and have no meaning in this context.